# How can I import an external rdf file into my ontology in protegè?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, protege4

I have annotated csv files in rdf format and now I want to import them into protegè to populate my ontology but I don't understand how to do it

Comment: Add an OWL import axiom to your ontology.

Comment: i don't know how, I was hoping there was a protege function that would allow this. Can u tell me how (with an example) and where i have to add this OWL import axiom? Step by step, thanks

Comment: that's all explained in the Protege documentation: http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/imported-ontologies/

Comment: I had already looked at the documentation and tried but it doesn't work, when I import the file like that the ontology disappears